# Liquid nesting For-Loop Syntax issue in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll, lightbox, liquid

### First time posting, so thanks in advance for your time `c:`

I'm using Jekyll to serve a portfolio. I'm using a portfolio plugin as well as a JS library called Lightbox. I have the portfolio plugin working. The ideal action is that every time the user clicks a portfolio item, it executes the lightbox (that's working). In order to for more images to be stored in the lightbox, I must give them the same data-title name.

My understanding is that I need to nest a for-loop within my current loop, to check for all items within the array to return any additional lightbox items.

### My `.yml` file reads like so:

```
title: Portfolio Title
description: A crazy portfolio item
bg-image: Test-01.png
lb-images:
  - Test-01.png
  - Test-02.png
  - Test-03.png`
```

### My `.md` file reads like so:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <!-- portfolio-item -->
{% assign projects = site.data.projects | get_projects_from_files | sort:'date' %}
{% for project in projects reversed %}

    <div class="flex-item" style="background-image: url(/img/projects/{{ project.bg-image }}); background-repeat: no-repeat">
      <a href="../images/projects/{{ project.lb-images[0] }}" data-lightbox="{{ project.title }}" data-title="{{ project.bg-image }}">
      <div id="overlay">
        <span id="reveal-text">
          <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
          <p>{{ project.category }}</p>
        </span>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    {% for project in projects %}
    <a href="../images/projects/{{ project.lb-images[{{forloop.index}}] }}" data-lightbox="{{ project.title }}" data-title="{{ project.bg-image }}"></a>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I assumed that the `forloop.index` would begin at `[1]` and then continue through that array until there are no more `lb-images`. But something's up. My guess is syntax or how I'm calling the data from the `.yml` file, or both.

Again thanks for your time.

Daniel

(edit: took out space in nested `endfor` loop, runs now but returns: `href="../images/projects/] }}"` and `data-title` and `data-lightbox` returns are for each `data.project` file instead of for each item in `data.project.lb-images`)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I'm not quite sure what symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: I expected `{{ forloop.index }}` to iterate [1, 2, 3.. for length of the array]. Instead the code is not handled and `}}` is just printed (from the fourth line from the end code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct loop to expose images for a project is:

```
{% assign projects = site.data.projects | get_projects_from_files | sort:'date' %}

<div class="flex-container">
  {% for project in projects reversed %}
    <!-- portfolio-item -->
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-image: url(/img/projects/{{ project.bg-image }}); background-repeat: no-repeat">
      <a href="../images/projects/{{ project.lb-images[0] }}" data-lightbox="{{ project.title }}" data-title="{{ project.bg-image }}">
      <div id="overlay">
        <span id="reveal-text">
          <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
          <p>{{ project.category }}</p>
        </span>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    {% for img in project.lb-images %}
      {% if forloop.first != true %}
        <a href="../images/projects/{{ img }}" data-lightbox="{{ project.title }}" data-title="{{ project.bg-image }}"></a>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[Liquid forloop documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops)

Comment: Thank you! This works! Question though, how would you incorporate `forloop.index` I was using it to start from the img array from [1...to length of array], since lb-images[0] appears in the previous div. I would rather move this for-loop up to the earlier `<a>` tag, but fear it'll repeat each element within the `<span>`

Comment: Edited my answer about forloop

Comment: Holy poo! That worked! Thank you for the documentation too. I understand where to throw the `forloop.first` items now... makes way more sense than nesting it within `{{ }}`

Comment: Cool ! So, maybe you can approve my answer.